# How to get text of another element to display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I am trying to change the text of a p tag when the p tag is clicked. At the moment it works I have the following HTML and jQuery

```
<p class='tile' data-default="Measurable" data-clicked="Some text blah blah." style="text-align: center;">Measurable</p>

<p class='tile' data-default="Unique and
own-able" data-clicked="Some text blah blah." style="text-align: center;">Unique and
own-able</p>

$('.tile').click(function(e) { // when the tile is clicked
    $('.tile').not(this).text($(not(this).attr('data-default'))); // Except the clicked tile all are restored to default data
    $(this).text($(this).attr('data-clicked')); // The clicked tile gets the replacer text
});
```

When I click on the first p tag it changes the text but the second p tag's default text is changed to Measureable. I understand how it is going wrong because it is getting the clicked p tags instance of data-default and putting it inside the second one.
I have tried to change the code to fix it but I end up breaking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.text(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) to set the text to its corresponding `data-default`:

```
$('.tile').not(this).text(function() {
  return $(this).data('default');
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xequkf7v/)

Comment: Ah thank you, so that is how you do it. I understand it now